# Instantiating different kinds of error records for a database operation

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, error-handling, factory-method

I've written code to be called from Powershell like so:

```
Rename-DatabaseUser -Name 'someuser' -NewName 'somenewuser'
```

I'm wondering if there's another way I can approach this. I want to create objects of the same type with slightly differing property values.

Here's the code I'm currently using now (RenameDatabaseUserCmdlet.cs):

```
namespace Company.Powershell.Module.Cmdlets
{
    using System.Management.Automation;

    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Rename, "DatabaseUser")]
    [Alias("rndbu")]
    public class RenameDatabaseUserCmdlet : PSCmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Object")]
        public DatabaseUser User { get; set; }

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "String")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Object")]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "String")]
        public string NewName { get; set; }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            DatabaseUser user;

            if (ParameterSetName == "String")
            {
                var ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace);
                ps.AddCommand("Get-DatabaseUser")
                  .AddParameter("Name", Name);

                foreach (var result in ps.Invoke())
                {
                    user = result?.BaseObject as DatabaseUser;
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        // This is where I'm not sure I'm doing it right.
                        WriteError(DatabaseErrorRecord.UserNotFound(Name));
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                user = User;
            }

            // Still more to do here...
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I create the objects.  In `DatabaseErrorRecord` I have multiple static methods which return an `ErrorRecord` object initialised slightly differently. These are some of the methods:

```
namespace Company.Powershell.Module
{
    using System;
    using System.Management.Automation;

    class DatabaseErrorRecord : ErrorRecord
    {
        // This is added just so it compiles, which is why I think I'm wrong.
        private DatabaseErrorRecord(Exception exception,
            string errorId,
            ErrorCategory errorCategory,
            object targetObject) : base(exception, errorId, errorCategory, targetObject)
        { }

        public static ErrorRecord UserNotFound(string userName)
        {
            return new ErrorRecord
            (
                new NullReferenceException($"The user '{userName}' could not be found in the database."),
                "UserNotFound",
                ErrorCategory.ObjectNotFound,
                null
            );
        }

        public static ErrorRecord DatabaseNotFound(string databaseName)
        {
            return new ErrorRecord
            (
                new NullReferenceException($"The database '{databaseName}' could not be found on the SQL Server instance."),
                "DatabaseNotFound",
                ErrorCategory.ObjectNotFound,
                null
            );
        }

        public static ErrorRecord PermissionConflict(string permissionA, string permissionB)
        {
            return new ErrorRecord
            (
                new InvalidOperationException($"Granting {permissionA} to this user would cause a conflict with {permissionB}."),
                "PermissionConflict",
                ErrorCategory.InvalidOperation,
                null
            );
        }
        // Other methods omitted...
    }
}
```

What is a good way to create objects of the same type, using slightly different arguments?

In each of these methods, when the `ErrorRecord` is created. The Exception, Error ID and Error Category will all be different. I would create these objects when I need them in code, but there's some instances where I would need the same object twice.

I'm still thinking this is wrong since I have to include the constructor despite the fact I will never use it.

Is there any other ways I could structure this?

Answer (score 4):

> There are no established scenarios for deriving from this class.
>
> [MSDN ErrorRecord](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.errorrecord(v=vs.85).aspx)

Which leads me to believe that there's no reason to derive a child class. Instead, change the name of `DatabaseErrorRecord` to `DatabaseErrorRecordFactory` and make it `static`. Do not derive from `ErrorRecord`. Instead, just have a static class with a bunch of static methods that return `ErrorRecord`s. This will remove the need to have any constructor at all.

```
public static class DatabaseErrorRecord
{
    public static ErrorRecord UserNotFound(string userName)
    {
        return new ErrorRecord
        (
            new NullReferenceException($"The user '{userName}' could not be found in the database."),
            "UserNotFound",
            ErrorCategory.ObjectNotFound,
            null
        );
    }
    // Other methods omitted...
}
```

---

Side note: I really like that you're taking advantage of the new C# 6 features. I'm a big fan of the Elvis operator.

One other thing I'd consider changing is that `NullReferenceException` though. It doesn't feel appropriate. An argument exception might be okay, but I think I'd create my own custom exception for this one.

Comment: 'Elvis operator'. I chuckled. :) The only reason I'm using `NullReferenceException` there is because the method can't continue with a null object. I asked a question about custom exceptions before and was told it was a bit pointless if I didn't extend the functionality of the exception because otherwise I was essentially just 'aliasing' the class.

Comment: Yeah. I don't have very good argument against NRE other than it could be misleading. I expect NRE's to be a certain class of coding errors. This use of it would surprise me.

Comment: Which exception might be more suitable then? Because MSDN says NRE's should be thrown when `there is an attempt to dereference a null object reference.` And considering that I'm not attempting to deference it because I already know it's null, it does seem `NullReferenceException` might be the wrong one to use.

Comment: What about an `ObjectNotFoundException`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objectnotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure, that class (I think) is meant for Entity Framework objects since it's in `System.Data.Entity`. I thought `ArgumentException` might be an idea, but it's not really a problem with the argument since the argument is valid. The code just can't run successfully with that particular argument.

Comment: [`KeyNotFoundException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception.aspx) might be a reasonable choice.

Comment: Good call @RobH, but I'm thinking the fact that we're having this much trouble finding one in the framework may justify a custom one.

Comment: @RubberDuck, maybe just create my own `ObjectNotFoundException` then? Since 'object' could refer to a database, user, domain account, role or permission. I won't be using Entity Framework in this project so hopefully it'll never clash.

Answer (score 2):

Targeting only the `ProcessRecord()` method.

You have a flaw here, because if the given `Name` is not found then the resulting `Collection<PSObject>` from the call to `ps.Invoke()` won't likely contain any items, hence the foreach won't iterate. This will result in `user` being `null`.
The other thing I am concerned is, if it is possible that the user's name isn't unique, the `user` variable will be overwritten for each iteration of the loop.

If the `Name` is unique, you shouldn't use a `foreach` at all and change the code to

```
        var result = ps.Invoke();
        if (result.count == 0)
        {
            // Database user not found
            // write your error

            return;
        }
        // assuming unique `Name`
        user = (DatabaseUser)result[0].BaseObject;
```

I have replaced the soft cast with a regular cast because IMO we can be sure that a `DatabaseUser` is returned at this point.

Comment: That's actually pretty clever, thanks for that. Name is unique in this case because SQL Server won't let you create identical user names.